# WinJS Angular Pivot Directive cannot be rendered

Tags: angularjs, windows-phone-8.1, winjs

It seems that the win-pivot angular directive does not render an actual pivot or pivot items on Windows Phone 8.1 JavaScript app. I'm using the following setup. In addition to the default code which is created with a new JavaScript Pivot App project, I have added the following directive on the default.html file.

From the following code only the left and right pivot headers are rendering (without styles). I have move else the reference from the old CSS files (WinJS 2.1) to the latests.

### Setup

- Windows Phone 8.1 VS Project
- WinJS 4.1
- Angular JS 1.4.1

Directive HTML

```
<div>
    <win-pivot>
        <win-pivot-left-header>Custom Left Header</win-pivot-left-header>
        <win-pivot-item header="'First'">
            Pivots are useful for varied content
        </win-pivot-item>
        <win-pivot-item header="'Second'">
            This Pivot  is boring however, it just has things like data bindings: {{ratings.length}}
        </win-pivot-item>
        <win-pivot-item header="'Tail...'">
            Because it's only purpose is to show how to create a Pivot
        </win-pivot-item>
        <win-pivot-right-header>Custom Right Header</win-pivot-right-header>
    </win-pivot>    
</div>
```

Directive JavaScript code

```
var ang = angular.module('app', ['winjs']);

ang.directive('app.testdir', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
    return {
        restrict: "AE",
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: "/scripts/app.html",
        scope: {
        },
        controller: ["$scope", Controller],
    };
    function Controller($scope) {

    }
}]);
```

default.html body

```
<body class="phone">
    <div>
        <div app.testdir></div>
    </div>
    <div id="contenthost" data-win-control="Application.PageControlNavigator" data-win-options="{home: '/pages/hub/hub.html'}"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: I have replaced the win-pivot directive with other winjs directives (e.g. listview, app commands, menus etc.) and worked fine.

Comment: Finally I downgraded to WinJS 2.1 and the same code works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

There was a bug in angular-winjs

I was also facing same issue and found that PivotItem is not rendering.
I changed the following line in angular-winjs.js ( 3.1 )

```
exists("PivotItem") && module.directive("winPivotItem", function () {
```

to

```
exists("Pivot") && module.directive("winPivotItem", function () {
```

and still it was not rendered. When I used ng-repeat for listing pivot items, it started rendering.

```
<win-pivot>
        <win-pivot-item ng-repeat="item_pivot in app.items" header="item_pivot.title">
               {{item_pivot.text}}
        </win-pivot-item>                        
  </win-pivot>
```

But due to some styling issues, it was not shown inside splitView. Changed some style also

```
<style>
    .win-pivot-header {
        color: #FFF !important;
    }
    .win-pivot-item {
        position:static !important;
    }
  </style>
```

and now pivot Items started displaying inside splitView.

**Update**: If you are using WinJS 4.3 Only style has to be changed

Comment: Now i try to use ng-switch to create individual templates for every single content. Or did you find out a way to use static win-pivot-items?

Comment: just update winjs4.2 and angularwinjs, static also will work.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is resolved in winjs 4.3. You can download 4.3 version of angular-winjs.js, ui.min and base.min. Also split view command is not included in the old version. That problem also gets resolved.

Comment: You may also have to do some css colour changes for the split view command to show up.